# System tag looks suspiciously like a meta tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What exactly is the [system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system) tag?  It doesn't even have a wiki.  Looks like a meta-tag to me.

Comment: It probably looks like a "Meta tag", too, because of that grey border :P

Comment: It does seem to be being used any-old way at the moment... The only valid non-meta use I could think of is for the System "process" or SYSTEM owner on processes or objects, and indeed it is used in that way occasionally...

Comment: Then maybe it could be split into `system-process` and `system-user`?

Comment: Yeah, that tag is much too broad. If there are valid subtags, maybe find a few examples where these would match, retag those, and then let's get rid of `[system]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking a few yields a few occurences of system:

- **System Volume Information**, might use a specific tag, but tag name would then be too long...
- **System Clock**, use [system-clock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-clock)?
- **System File / Folder**, use [system-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-file) or [system-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-files) (same for folder tags)?
- **System Disk**, used to refer to first / main drive, use [system-disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-disk)?
- **System Device**, why not just call these devices and use the [devices](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/devices)?
- **System Administrator**, which could just be called administrator, just use [administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/administrator)?
- **System Restore**, use [system-restore](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-restore)?
- **System Partition**, might be similar to System Disk, use [system-partition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-partition)?
- **Computer System**, used to point to the computer in general, these can go...
- **Other type of system**, can probably also go as the tag itself often wouldn't be on-topic.

---

Assuming this is slightly representative, this summarizes to three possible scenarios:

- **System should be used as a prefix in another tag** if it is an important detail,  [system-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-file)
- **System should not be used as a prefix** if it doesn't add anything, [administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/administrator) and [device](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/device).
- **System should be dropped**, it's not a prefix to another tag and all questions are about (computer) systems thus the tag doesn't add anything at all to the question.

From all these scenarios we see that the questions need to be retagged and [system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system) itself should disappear, by either combining it with another tag using system as a prefix or by removing the tag.

---

The list of questions I have checked follows:

- [Protecting a mounted drive's data from deletion](https://superuser.com/questions/529841/protecting-a-mounted-drives-data-from-deletion) (System Volume Information)
- [Dell Latitude C510 system clock](https://superuser.com/questions/523440/dell-latitude-c510-system-clock) (System Clock)
- [Possible to see content of TCP/IP connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/522153/possible-to-see-content-of-tcp-ip-connection) (Computer System)
- [Recommended software for simple inventory system?](https://superuser.com/questions/520778/recommended-software-for-simple-inventory-system) (Other type of system)
- [Copying windows 8 Users folder having long long paths](https://superuser.com/questions/518889/copying-windows-8-users-folder-having-long-long-paths) (System File)
- [Force system crash on hard hang](https://superuser.com/questions/517610/force-system-crash-on-hard-hang) (Computer System)
- [System.exe explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/519179/system-exe-explanation) (Other type of system)
- [Linux User Permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/515069/linux-user-permissions) (Computer System)
- [How do I view the OS installation date on solaris 10](https://superuser.com/questions/514546/how-do-i-view-the-os-installation-date-on-solaris-10) (Computer System)
- [why all site show me thing 13 hours ago when it's just happen to me?](https://superuser.com/questions/509949/why-all-site-show-me-thing-13-hours-ago-when-its-just-happen-to-me) (System Clock)
- [Working Windows 7 disk becomes not a system disk](https://superuser.com/questions/508740/working-windows-7-disk-becomes-not-a-system-disk) (System Disk)
- [Start ProcessMonitor will unexpectedly execute another irrelevant exe](https://superuser.com/questions/504930/start-processmonitor-will-unexpectedly-execute-another-irrelevant-exe) (Computer System)
- [Disk Activity? What does it mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/494302/disk-activity-what-does-it-mean) (Computer System)
- [System shuts down immediately after few sconds](https://superuser.com/questions/490845/system-shuts-down-immediately-after-few-sconds) (Computer System)
- [Windows says "access denied" when copying files ...](https://superuser.com/questions/487696/windows-says-access-denied-when-copying-files-from-one-partition-to-another) (Computer System)
- [Why is My USB ports not connecting anything?](https://superuser.com/questions/482591/why-is-my-usb-ports-not-connecting-anything) (System Device)
- [New Computer freezing up at random](https://superuser.com/questions/477762/new-computer-freezing-up-at-random) (Computer System)
- [Windows Remote Desktop (mstsc) Keyboard Sticking](https://superuser.com/questions/473449/windows-remote-desktop-mstsc-keyboard-sticking) (System Administrator)
- ["My Documents/My Pictures" deleted on XP. "My Documents" copied on W7. ...](https://superuser.com/questions/467947/my-documents-my-pictures-deleted-on-xp-my-documents-copied-on-w7-my-pictu) (System Folder)
- [System Admin Training (online)](https://superuser.com/questions/466546/system-admin-training-online) (System Administrator)
- [How to create Image of your system which has lot of software installed](https://superuser.com/questions/459982/how-to-create-image-of-your-system-which-has-lot-of-software-installed) (Computer System)
- [How can computers figure out the current minute, but not hour/year?](https://superuser.com/questions/455340/how-can-computers-figure-out-the-current-minute-but-not-hour-year) (System Clock)
- [Telnet and system root password can differ?](https://superuser.com/questions/455239/telnet-and-system-root-password-can-differ) (System Administrator)
- [how to uninstall netbeans 7.1.2 after system restore in windows xp](https://superuser.com/questions/452096/how-to-uninstall-netbeans-7-1-2-after-system-restore-in-windows-xp) (System Restore)
- [Change the system partition in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/448341/change-the-system-partition-in-windows-xp) (System Partition)

---

The remaining unchecked questions list follows, for anyone who wants to check some more:

```
 - [Any ramifications to disabling ClearPageFile](https://superuser.com/questions/446593/any-ramifications-to-disabling-clearpagefile)
 - [Any utility to check RAM performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/445118/any-utility-to-check-ram-performance)
 - [error installing a program becuase the admin has set a block on it?](https://superuser.com/questions/444237/error-installing-a-program-becuase-the-admin-has-set-a-block-on-it)
 - [Getting an boot error when starting computer](https://superuser.com/questions/441041/getting-an-boot-error-when-starting-computer)
 - [Laptop keeps dropping connection and coming back to same screen](https://superuser.com/questions/438238/laptop-keeps-dropping-connection-and-coming-back-to-same-screen)
 - [How to &quot;cd&quot; into system files](https://superuser.com/questions/434829/how-to-cd-into-system-files)
 - [What software can I use to test my hardware?](https://superuser.com/questions/432891/what-software-can-i-use-to-test-my-hardware)
 - [Unknown username or bad password on network drive mounted by SYSTEM user on a Scheduled Task](https://superuser.com/questions/432626/unknown-username-or-bad-password-on-network-drive-mounted-by-system-user-on-a-sc)
 - [Does Windows 7 require the Disk 0 Partition 1 : System Reserved Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/430981/does-windows-7-require-the-disk-0-partition-1-system-reserved-partition)
 - [How to start-up desktop shortcuts when Windows starts?](https://superuser.com/questions/429940/how-to-start-up-desktop-shortcuts-when-windows-starts)
 - [Computer Restart When I Insert a USB Drive (Othe Removable Device)](https://superuser.com/questions/426236/computer-restart-when-i-insert-a-usb-drive-othe-removable-device)
 - [can I restore only the system files with time machine (revert from 10.7.4 to 10.7.3)?](https://superuser.com/questions/423353/can-i-restore-only-the-system-files-with-time-machine-revert-from-10-7-4-to-10)
 - [Switch back to IDE from RAID](https://superuser.com/questions/418829/switch-back-to-ide-from-raid)
 - [Creating exFAT partition (for PC &amp; Mac) alongside bootable HFS+ partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/412272/creating-exfat-partition-for-pc-mac-alongside-bootable-hfs-partition)
 - [How can I move the location of ntuser files](https://superuser.com/questions/411531/how-can-i-move-the-location-of-ntuser-files)
 - [What can I do if my system crashes frequently?](https://superuser.com/questions/410662/what-can-i-do-if-my-system-crashes-frequently)
 - [The &quot;System&quot; process has my BCD open(windows 7)?](https://superuser.com/questions/410541/the-system-process-has-my-bcd-openwindows-7)
 - [Can Git be used when &quot;experimenting&quot;, changing drivers and software on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/409286/can-git-be-used-when-experimenting-changing-drivers-and-software-on-linux)
 - [System Recovery Operating System not listed](https://superuser.com/questions/408553/system-recovery-operating-system-not-listed)
 - [Which way can I avoid Dropbox syncing older files when restoring a CloneZilla image?](https://superuser.com/questions/407954/which-way-can-i-avoid-dropbox-syncing-older-files-when-restoring-a-clonezilla-im)
 - [Hp desktop system recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/406267/hp-desktop-system-recovery)
 - [Parental controls floods system.log with errors](https://superuser.com/questions/402833/parental-controls-floods-system-log-with-errors)
 - [How can I update the System Drivers in my C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32 Directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/396362/how-can-i-update-the-system-drivers-in-my-c-windows-system32-directory)
 - [Getting &quot;The HOME environmental variable changed out from under us!&quot; in system log](https://superuser.com/questions/391782/getting-the-home-environmental-variable-changed-out-from-under-us-in-system-l)
 - [windows 7 - lock a file for writing by only one program?](https://superuser.com/questions/381515/windows-7-lock-a-file-for-writing-by-only-one-program)
 - [Why is event-log time different from taskbar time?](https://superuser.com/questions/381083/why-is-event-log-time-different-from-taskbar-time)
 - [Windows system restore prior to truecrypt system encryption?](https://superuser.com/questions/380594/windows-system-restore-prior-to-truecrypt-system-encryption)
 - [Gparted will not resize Windows XP system partition](https://superuser.com/questions/379853/gparted-will-not-resize-windows-xp-system-partition)
 - [Error message - kexts installed improperly](https://superuser.com/questions/378215/error-message-kexts-installed-improperly)
 - [Eclipse using huge amount of System Memory](https://superuser.com/questions/377682/eclipse-using-huge-amount-of-system-memory)
 - [Reinstall Windows under TrueCrypt](https://superuser.com/questions/375452/reinstall-windows-under-truecrypt)
 - [On Windows 7, how can I retrieve/set system (not administrator) password?](https://superuser.com/questions/374331/on-windows-7-how-can-i-retrieve-set-system-not-administrator-password)
 - [How can I migrate multiple operating systems to a different hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/373499/how-can-i-migrate-multiple-operating-systems-to-a-different-hard-drive)
 - [How to move System Partition to another drive in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/372334/how-to-move-system-partition-to-another-drive-in-windows-7)
 - [Linux file system for a big file server](https://superuser.com/questions/371469/linux-file-system-for-a-big-file-server)
 - [system process using constantly 20% cpu - win7 pro 64](https://superuser.com/questions/371126/system-process-using-constantly-20-cpu-win7-pro-64)
 - [Windows kiosk / restore functionality](https://superuser.com/questions/370080/windows-kiosk-restore-functionality)
 - [Serial mouse does&#39;t work without restart, but USB mouse will. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/369567/serial-mouse-doest-work-without-restart-but-usb-mouse-will-why)
 - [Install Windows XP on computer that has &quot;System Reserved&quot; partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/369405/install-windows-xp-on-computer-that-has-system-reserved-partition)
 - [Inadvertently entered a password into the BIOS and now I can&#39;t use my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/368481/inadvertently-entered-a-password-into-the-bios-and-now-i-cant-use-my-laptop)
 - [Is it possible to log every system/application pop-up window and see it later in Windows XP and later?](https://superuser.com/questions/366848/is-it-possible-to-log-every-system-application-pop-up-window-and-see-it-later-in)
 - [How to make conky list top 5 processes?](https://superuser.com/questions/363337/how-to-make-conky-list-top-5-processes)
 - [apache (don&#39;t send) error message on every system restart](https://superuser.com/questions/363312/apache-dont-send-error-message-on-every-system-restart)
 - [When I format my USB drive in NTFS, it creates a &quot;System Volume Information&quot; folder – is it a virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/360672/when-i-format-my-usb-drive-in-ntfs-it-creates-a-system-volume-information-fol)
 - [What can I do if msvcr80.dll is missing?](https://superuser.com/questions/356486/what-can-i-do-if-msvcr80-dll-is-missing)
 - [System for computations](https://superuser.com/questions/349830/system-for-computations)
 - [Best way to *instantly* tell which process is slowing down your system?](https://superuser.com/questions/333876/best-way-to-instantly-tell-which-process-is-slowing-down-your-system)
 - [Why does Windows 7 have three system partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/333846/why-does-windows-7-have-three-system-partitions)
 - [windows system backup does not recognize second hard disk anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/333643/windows-system-backup-does-not-recognize-second-hard-disk-anymore)
 - [Some files in System32 not accessible outside Explorer on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/330941/some-files-in-system32-not-accessible-outside-explorer-on-windows-7)
 - [When is the data in the journal written to the disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/329004/when-is-the-data-in-the-journal-written-to-the-disk)
 - [How to find the hardware chipset information?](https://superuser.com/questions/328366/how-to-find-the-hardware-chipset-information)
 - [Why does my System Process use 50% of CPU time?](https://superuser.com/questions/322341/why-does-my-system-process-use-50-of-cpu-time)
 - [Can BLANK computer be reinstalled (OS) with system image?](https://superuser.com/questions/320906/can-blank-computer-be-reinstalled-os-with-system-image)
 - [Get List of Hard Drive Letter and Types From Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/318861/get-list-of-hard-drive-letter-and-types-from-registry)
 - [Cloning Windows 7 partition](https://superuser.com/questions/318025/cloning-windows-7-partition)
 - [Why are there missing .dll files while installing?](https://superuser.com/questions/314992/why-are-there-missing-dll-files-while-installing)
 - [How to temporarily disable a service running as Local System?](https://superuser.com/questions/310244/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-service-running-as-local-system)
 - [What is the &quot;You have new mail&quot; message in Linux/UNIX?](https://superuser.com/questions/306163/what-is-the-you-have-new-mail-message-in-linux-unix)
 - [cache architecture](https://superuser.com/questions/302784/cache-architecture)
 - [System.exe trying to connect microsoft ISP](https://superuser.com/questions/300738/system-exe-trying-to-connect-microsoft-isp)
 - [Where does msinfo32.exe get it&#39;s data from?](https://superuser.com/questions/298211/where-does-msinfo32-exe-get-its-data-from)
 - [How to stop programs from ever running again?](https://superuser.com/questions/297361/how-to-stop-programs-from-ever-running-again)
 - [How to start DOS on a PC with just HDD (no FDD/CD/USB drives)](https://superuser.com/questions/294638/how-to-start-dos-on-a-pc-with-just-hdd-no-fdd-cd-usb-drives)
 - [Chkdsk Questions](https://superuser.com/questions/292338/chkdsk-questions)
 - [Notification Area Balloon Windows 7 not working](https://superuser.com/questions/291692/notification-area-balloon-windows-7-not-working)
 - [How can I change the letter assigned to a drive by Windows, without using a Windows program?](https://superuser.com/questions/287203/how-can-i-change-the-letter-assigned-to-a-drive-by-windows-without-using-a-wind)
 - [Will system restore &quot;restore&quot; a wubi root.disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/286678/will-system-restore-restore-a-wubi-root-disk)
 - [Spooler subsystem app has encountered a problem and needs to close](https://superuser.com/questions/284781/spooler-subsystem-app-has-encountered-a-problem-and-needs-to-close)
 - [Change date of VMware station](https://superuser.com/questions/283776/change-date-of-vmware-station)
 - [Recover Shift deleted file in windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/283000/recover-shift-deleted-file-in-windows-xp)
 - [System32 and SysWOW64 on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/281730/system32-and-syswow64-on-windows-7)
 - [Restart Macbook Pro if &quot;Restart, Sleep, Shut Down&quot; buttons are hidden](https://superuser.com/questions/276965/restart-macbook-pro-if-restart-sleep-shut-down-buttons-are-hidden)
 - [&#39;no file system defined&#39; while installing ubuntu by Wubi!](https://superuser.com/questions/276592/no-file-system-defined-while-installing-ubuntu-by-wubi)
 - [What is the SYSTEM group in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/276388/what-is-the-system-group-in-windows-7)
 - [Paranoia Of Using Credit Card Online](https://superuser.com/questions/275950/paranoia-of-using-credit-card-online)
 - [how to use sysprep and imagex for disk with one than partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/275937/how-to-use-sysprep-and-imagex-for-disk-with-one-than-partitions)
 - [XP System32 folder - DLL magically being replaced after deletion?](https://superuser.com/questions/269939/xp-system32-folder-dll-magically-being-replaced-after-deletion)
 - [Batch file close/kill a System Tray/systray program](https://superuser.com/questions/268717/batch-file-close-kill-a-system-tray-systray-program)
 - [PowerShell - environment vars - differentiating between user and system vars](https://superuser.com/questions/267209/powershell-environment-vars-differentiating-between-user-and-system-vars)
 - [How big a partition does Windows 7 require if programs and data are on other partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/266703/how-big-a-partition-does-windows-7-require-if-programs-and-data-are-on-other-par)
 - [How to extract environment variables from system restore point, Windows 7 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/265532/how-to-extract-environment-variables-from-system-restore-point-windows-7-64-bit)
 - [Windows hosts file equivalent on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/262211/windows-hosts-file-equivalent-on-mac)
 - [What HTFS means?](https://superuser.com/questions/260599/what-htfs-means)
 - [Windows 7 Backup and Restore is not seeing all partitions of my hard drive ](https://superuser.com/questions/259832/windows-7-backup-and-restore-is-not-seeing-all-partitions-of-my-hard-drive)
 - [What I should know about memory management?](https://superuser.com/questions/259236/what-i-should-know-about-memory-management)
 - [System idle process](https://superuser.com/questions/250004/system-idle-process)
 - [Can I move Windows from one computer to another if the two are hardware-identical?](https://superuser.com/questions/247154/can-i-move-windows-from-one-computer-to-another-if-the-two-are-hardware-identica)
 - [Measured with &#39;time&#39; command, why is process spending so much sys time as compared with similar system](https://superuser.com/questions/242444/measured-with-time-command-why-is-process-spending-so-much-sys-time-as-compar)
 - [Is it possible to clone system drive in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/242322/is-it-possible-to-clone-system-drive-in-windows-7)
 - [Is weak bios battery will cause system date to change but not the time?](https://superuser.com/questions/237388/is-weak-bios-battery-will-cause-system-date-to-change-but-not-the-time)
 - [Differences between local and remote file system drivers in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/237205/differences-between-local-and-remote-file-system-drivers-in-windows)
 - [What&#39;s the average amount of processes in OS X Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/229854/whats-the-average-amount-of-processes-in-os-x-snow-leopard)
 - [Do registry issues with Windows 7 persist through a recovery from a system image?](https://superuser.com/questions/221788/do-registry-issues-with-windows-7-persist-through-a-recovery-from-a-system-image)
 - [Has anyone managed to compile nmon for freebsd? or alternatives?](https://superuser.com/questions/221103/has-anyone-managed-to-compile-nmon-for-freebsd-or-alternatives)
 - [How can I access the System Account in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/220768/how-can-i-access-the-system-account-in-windows-7)
 - [NTUSER.DAT files locked by System process - logging in as TEMP profile](https://superuser.com/questions/217591/ntuser-dat-files-locked-by-system-process-logging-in-as-temp-profile)
 - [accessing folder](https://superuser.com/questions/215633/accessing-folder)
 - [Lenovo System Update Breaks Windows Live](https://superuser.com/questions/210498/lenovo-system-update-breaks-windows-live)
 - [HP Pavilion dv5t - 1000 system restore does not complete](https://superuser.com/questions/204243/hp-pavilion-dv5t-1000-system-restore-does-not-complete)
 - [DOS Command Lines Move files to folders named with previous month](https://superuser.com/questions/204047/dos-command-lines-move-files-to-folders-named-with-previous-month)
 - [System process consuming CPU in Vista; mostly in ntkrnlpa:KiDispatchInterrupt](https://superuser.com/questions/203436/system-process-consuming-cpu-in-vista-mostly-in-ntkrnlpakidispatchinterrupt)
 - [No POST on previously working system](https://superuser.com/questions/202899/no-post-on-previously-working-system)
 - [System configuration tool for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/196031/system-configuration-tool-for-windows)
 - [Which directories are private to specific users by default on UNIX-based systems?](https://superuser.com/questions/195301/which-directories-are-private-to-specific-users-by-default-on-unix-based-systems)
 - [Some Windows System files cannot be deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/183147/some-windows-system-files-cannot-be-deleted)
 - [How can I see how much network traffic each thread is doing in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/178094/how-can-i-see-how-much-network-traffic-each-thread-is-doing-in-linux)
 - [Install-free app to get mobo model + Windows version?](https://superuser.com/questions/174697/install-free-app-to-get-mobo-model-windows-version)
 - [Is it possible to reinstall/fix Mac OS X&#39;s system ruby without doing a complete OS reinstall?](https://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete)
 - [Are hardware crashes logged somewhere?](https://superuser.com/questions/162310/are-hardware-crashes-logged-somewhere)
 - [How to kill all processes in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/161531/how-to-kill-all-processes-in-linux)
 - [Help me in free the ram](https://superuser.com/questions/161528/help-me-in-free-the-ram)
 - [How do I make a simple shortcut on my Mac to go to screen saver mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/156452/how-do-i-make-a-simple-shortcut-on-my-mac-to-go-to-screen-saver-mode)
 - [How do i delete a copied`System Volume Information`?](https://superuser.com/questions/155315/how-do-i-delete-a-copiedsystem-volume-information)
 - [How to change the amount of RAM displayed in System Properties](https://superuser.com/questions/153804/how-to-change-the-amount-of-ram-displayed-in-system-properties)
 - [What is a raid &quot;sub-system&quot;?](https://superuser.com/questions/150344/what-is-a-raid-sub-system)
 - [Physically moving a hard drive from older iMac (c2d) to new iMac (i7)?](https://superuser.com/questions/148320/physically-moving-a-hard-drive-from-older-imac-c2d-to-new-imac-i7)
 - [List of Applications on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/147423/list-of-applications-on-mac-os-x)
 - [Changing system sounds in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/144775/changing-system-sounds-in-mac-os-x)
 - [Can I access this Mac system remotely?](https://superuser.com/questions/144099/can-i-access-this-mac-system-remotely)
 - [How to remove NTFS system files from a previous Vista installation](https://superuser.com/questions/141255/how-to-remove-ntfs-system-files-from-a-previous-vista-installation)
 - [System statistics in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/133061/system-statistics-in-ubuntu)
 - [I want to change hard drive. How to move system partition with Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/132272/i-want-to-change-hard-drive-how-to-move-system-partition-with-windows-7)
 - [Mac shortcut keys: How to add a generic &quot;About  - [app]&quot; to keyboard shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/130602/mac-shortcut-keys-how-to-add-a-generic-about-app-to-keyboard-shortcuts)
 - [Windows 7 XP mode fonts too small](https://superuser.com/questions/128023/windows-7-xp-mode-fonts-too-small)
 - [Installing a Software From The Server!! HELP!](https://superuser.com/questions/127507/installing-a-software-from-the-server-help)
 - [Why is the System process listening on Port 443?](https://superuser.com/questions/125455/why-is-the-system-process-listening-on-port-443)
 - [System files not hidden Win XP](https://superuser.com/questions/118942/system-files-not-hidden-win-xp)
 - [Why does my computer keep rebooting when running Visual Studio 2008?](https://superuser.com/questions/115995/why-does-my-computer-keep-rebooting-when-running-visual-studio-2008)
 - [Tool to determine motherboard in Windows or Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/114458/tool-to-determine-motherboard-in-windows-or-linux)
 - [OS Label at System Boot Menu](https://superuser.com/questions/108037/os-label-at-system-boot-menu)
 - [Export Command -- Intended Effect?](https://superuser.com/questions/94675/export-command-intended-effect)
 - [How can I find out which driver/file is being loaded when the system hangs during the Windows 7 boot process?](https://superuser.com/questions/93727/how-can-i-find-out-which-driver-file-is-being-loaded-when-the-system-hangs-durin)
 - [Disk Boot Failure - Insert System Disk and Press Enter](https://superuser.com/questions/93531/disk-boot-failure-insert-system-disk-and-press-enter)
 - [System Restore takes up more space as time goes by](https://superuser.com/questions/89658/system-restore-takes-up-more-space-as-time-goes-by)
 - [How to analyze Process Explorer&#39;s graphs and data?](https://superuser.com/questions/87605/how-to-analyze-process-explorers-graphs-and-data)
 - [Linux Disk Naming Convention](https://superuser.com/questions/81034/linux-disk-naming-convention)
 - [Non-virus originated cases of System Volume Information folder existance on removable media](https://superuser.com/questions/74144/non-virus-originated-cases-of-system-volume-information-folder-existance-on-remo)
 - [Ubuntu 9.10, systray(system tray) icons are missing](https://superuser.com/questions/73195/ubuntu-9-10-systraysystem-tray-icons-are-missing)
 - [Is it safe to run an operating system from an USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/67612/is-it-safe-to-run-an-operating-system-from-an-usb-flash-drive)
 - [Set local time in windows xp](https://superuser.com/questions/58711/set-local-time-in-windows-xp)
 - [How do you recreate the System Recovery environment in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/55585/how-do-you-recreate-the-system-recovery-environment-in-windows-7)
 - [Overview of MIPS-per-watt?](https://superuser.com/questions/51733/overview-of-mips-per-watt)
 - [Document Management System](https://superuser.com/questions/43321/document-management-system)
 - [Whys is System process listening on Port 80?](https://superuser.com/questions/43307/whys-is-system-process-listening-on-port-80)
 - [repairing &quot;System Restore&quot;](https://superuser.com/questions/25142/repairing-system-restore)
 - [Running OS off a dedicated Hard Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/9224/running-os-off-a-dedicated-hard-drive)
 - [Windows registry and system cleaner applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/6668/windows-registry-and-system-cleaner-applications)
 - [Windows: How to change the system/dialog font?](https://superuser.com/questions/5004/windows-how-to-change-the-system-dialog-font)
 - [Access linux file systems from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2175/access-linux-file-systems-from-windows)
 - [Buying a new Mac Pro - which CPU/how many? And how much RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/97456/buying-a-new-mac-pro-which-cpu-how-many-and-how-much-ram)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for summarizing all of that. IMO `[device]` is much too broad to be a useful tag — what is a system device even? Apart from that, generally agree with your suggestions. I think we'll find some more bad tag combinations like [`[system][restore]`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system+restore) meaning `[system-restore]`.

Comment: Yeah, if you skim the list you see system process is still missing and I guess there aren't much left there. Indeed, `[device(s)]` might not be feasible, although there currently is a [tag:devices] tag though.